# php: ldap_add is asynchronous?

Tags: php, asynchronous, ldap

I'm developing a PHP app in which a create ldap items. And when I add an item, I need to get it right away because I need to know its creation timestamp for some purpose.

I then have :

- ldap_add($ds, $dn, $data)
- ldap_search($ds, $root, $some_filter)

Almost every time, I get the right result in the search, but it happens me twice that : 
- the right entry was created (I could check it afterward)
- the search didn't find anything.

After some googling, I found that there are two C functions to add an entry: ldap_add, and ldap_add_s, the first one being asynchronous.
My best guess it that :

- the PHP ldap_add calls the C function ldap_add (asynchronous)
- it returns "true" to say "it's going to be right" (but not "it was right")
- in some case, my search occurs when the ldap_add is still running in background, and then I get an empty result.

Would this explanation make sense? Is there any other solution that wait a little bit if the search returns nothing, and try again?

Best,

V.

Answer (score 0):

No PHP use `ldap_add_s` : https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/ldap/ldap.c#L1444

So as long as your LDAP server doesn't lie, which might happen with some multi-master configuration, your search result must contain the value you just added.